# Is there an idiomatic way to avoid long Clojure string literals?

Tags: clojure, idioms

Various Clojure style guides recommend avoiding lines longer than 80 characters. I am wondering if there is an idiomatic way to avoid long `String` literals.

While it's common these days to have wide screens, I still agree that long lines should be avoided.

Here are some examples (I'm tempted to follow the first):

```
;; break the String literal with `str`
(println (str
    "The quick brown fox "
    "jumps over the lazy dog"))

;; break the String literal with `join`
(println (join " " [
    "The quick brown fox"
    "jumps over the lazy dog"]))
```

I am aware that Clojure supports multi-line `String` literals, but using this approach has the undesired effect of the newline characters being interpreted, e.g. using the `repl`:

```
user=> (println "The quick brown fox
  #_=>   jumps over the lazy dog")
The quick brown fox
  jumps over the lazy dog
```

Comment: @Chiron: "Is there an idiomatic way to avoid long String literals?" is not really a question? Really? Was my primary education all a lie?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should probably store the string inside an external text file, and read the file from your code. If you still feel the need to store the string in your code, go ahead and use `str`.

EDIT:

As requested, I will demonstrate how you can read long strings at compile time.

```
(defmacro compile-time-slurp [file]
  (slurp file))
```

Use it like this:

```
(def long-string (compile-time-slurp "longString.txt"))
```

You may invent similar macros to handle Java Properties files, XML/JSON configuration, SQL queries, HTML, or whatever else you need.

Comment: You probably shouldn't put the string in a text file most of the time, unless we're talking really big text. It adds operational cost, performance cost and code complexity. The correct answer is to use (str).

Comment: This is Clojure. `(slurp "myBigString.txt")` does not increase the complexity of the code (and is less complex than in-string newlines). If performance of file IO is an issue, then the command may be run at compile time via macro.

Comment: It introduces unneeded possible failures that you'd now need to account for, which is higher code complexity. Are you seriously suggesting people put longer then 80 character strings in individual text files? What happened to the whole idea of side effect free functions? Only put texts in files when they're *really* large, or are externally provided, or dynamically generated and need to persist.

Comment: As a second note, you do not need in string newlines in Clojure, string literals can span multiple lines and will retain the newlines as part of the string.

Comment: Strings need to be easily editable by the developer. For multi-line strings, my own experience is that it is far easier to edit them in text files than in literals in the source code. The added complexity of getting the code to read the file is worth it for the ease of editing the text as a separate file.

Comment: I don't see why, as a dev, it's harder to edit a .clj text file then it would be a .txt one. If you find it easier, that's fine, but this is not an idiomatic way of writing Clojure, and as an engineer, it would not pass my code review unless you could justify the additional cost of why you're reading your exception msg from a text file. Not breaking the 80 line count would not cut it.

Comment: Have you ever tried to edit the sentence structure of a paragraph that's been defined as concatenated strings in source code? You're constantly shifting words from one line to another, trying to make text that will both look good to the user and not appear hideous inside your source code. Text files solve this issue entirely - and they are so *complex* to handle that they're taught in introductory CS courses.

Comment: You're arguing for minute grievances. How often do you actually change a string versus the time it takes you to do so? Reading it from a file has real implications on the software, while shuffling a string only has implications on you. You have to deal with possible path issues on deployments, like a missing resource or the resource not being where it should. You have the potential for IO failures. The performance cost of opening and closing a file and blocking on IO.

Comment: This is Clojure. We can read from a file at compile time, and deal with IO failures and missing resources at compile time. This approach keeps the code cleaner, makes the strings easier to read and modify for the developer, and uses the features of the language to your benefit. As a result, I don't have to deal with any of the issues you mentioned once the code is deployed. At this point, we're beyond a difference of opinion - the last four sentences you posted are actually objectively wrong.

Comment: I'd love to know how you read from it at compile time? And if you have such a solution, I'd update the answer to specify this and explain how to do it.

Comment: Keep in mind this is only true if the code calling the macro is AOT compiled. If not, it will expand at load-time, which means you can still suffer from the file missing, or being on the wrong path, or disk errors, etc. Causing your code to possibly fail to properly load.

Answer (score 4):

The most idiomatic ways I know of are the following:

**1)** Use (str) to split the string over multiple lines.

```
(str "User " (:user context)
     " is now logged in.")
```

This is probably the most idiomatic usage. I've seen this done in multiple libraries and projects. It is fast, since (str) uses a StringBuilder under the hood. It also allows you to mix code in transparently, as I've done in the example.

**2)** Allow strings to break the 80 char limit by themselves, when it makes sense.

```
(format
  "User %s is now logged in."
  (:user context))
```

Basically, it's ok to break the 80 char limit for strings. Chances are it's less likely you care about reading the string when you work with the code, and on the off chance you need to, exceptionally, you'll need to scroll horizontally.

I've wrapped the string in a (format) here to be able to inject code similarly to my previous example. You don't need to.

---

Less idiomatic ways would be:

**3)** Put your strings in files and load them from there.

```
(slurp "/path/to/userLoggedIn.txt")
```

With a file: `/path/to/userLoggedIn.txt` containing:

```
User logged in.
```

I advise against this because:

- It introduces IO side effects
- It has the potential to fail, say the path is wrong, the resource is missing or corrupted, the disk errors, etc.
- It has performance implications, disk reads are slow.
- Its hard to inject content from code if you need too.

I would say do this only if your text is **really** big. Or if the content of the string needs to be changed by non devs. Or if the content is obtained externally.

**4)** Have a namespace where you def all your strings in, and load them from there.

```
(ns msgs)
(defn logged-in-msg [user]
  (format
"User %s is now logged in."
    user))
```

Which you then use like this:

```
(msgs/logged-in-msg (:user context))
```

I prefer this over #3. You still need to allow to use #2 here, where it's ok to have strings break the 80 char limit. In fact, here you put strings by themselves on a line, so they are easy to format. If you use code analysis like checkstyle, you can exclude this file from the rule. It also does not suffer from the issues of #3.

---

If you are going with #3 or #4, you probably have a special use case for your strings, like internationalization, or having business edit them, etc. In those cases, you might be better served building a more robust solution, that could be inspired from the above methods, or using a library that specializes in those use cases.

Answer (score 3):

I find it convenient to use `str` to create strings and use character literals such as `\newline` or `\tab` instead of "\n" to break them.
I rarely violate the 80-column rule this way.

Answer (score 1):

```clj
(defmacro strs
  ([]
   "")
  ([a]
   (if (string? a) `~a `(str ~a)))
  ([a & more]
   `(str
      ~@(->> (cons a more)
             (partition-by string?)
             (mapcat #(if (string? (first %)) (cons (apply str %) nil) %))))))
```

Usage:

```clj
(strs "one "
      "two "
      3
      " four" " five")
; => "one two 3 four five"
```

Neighbouring literal strings will be concatenated at compile time.