# How can I break lines in Clojure?

Tags: clojure, line-breaks

In my Clojure source code there are some strings that are too long, like 400 characters. I would like to breakline these string.
In Java I would do something like:

```
String myStrig = "I am a long" 
                  + "String";
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Simply enough:

```
(str "I am a long "
     "string")
```

Comment: Is it not possible to do it without a function? only with a line break character or something like that.

Comment: @fiso, why? I mean, in Java you're using the `+` concatenation operator. `str` is the concatenation function in Clojure, just as `+` is its Java equivalent.

Comment: ...which is to say, no, there isn't anything which would do it in the reader. You could write a macro that ensures that `str` is run at compile-time if you really, _really_ cared -- but given as the compiler can determine `(str "foo" "bar")` to be a constant, it could do that ahead-of-time anyhow.

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74650273/617851